# Как определить содержание первой ячейки в таблице при нажатии на любую ячейку строки?

Tags: javascript, html

Как определить содержание первой ячейки в таблице при нажатии на любую ячейку строки?

Comment: @florian92, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вам на чистом JS? Тогда можно так:

```
var td = document.querySelectorAll('#tbl td');
[].forEach.call(td, function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log(this.parentNode.firstElementChild.innerHTML);
    }, false);
});
```

С jQuery так:

```
$('#tbl td').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
});
```